# Cannot close dynamically created jquery UI dialog box through setTimeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating a jquery UI dialog box dynamically like this

```
$('.panel-body').append
('<div style=\'display:none\' id=\'dialog\' title=\'Message\'><p>' + $scope.successMessage + '</p></div>');
```

In the very next line, I have added some close to automatically close the dialog box.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog(
      {
          open: function(event, ui) 
          {
              setTimeout(function()
              {
                  alert(1);
                  $('#dialog').dialog('close'); 
              }, 3000
              );
          }
      });
```

However, I get this error message.

cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

I guess this is due to the fact that my dialog box is dynamic, but I cannot solve the problem.

Comment: Could you recreate a small sandbox in JSFiddle so we can poke around?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Dialog acts somehow strange... this works (please like if you appreciate)

If you want to open the dialog with a button or event, you can encapsulate the open & timeout calls into that button or event action.

```js
//Needs jquery UI as well
$scope={successMessage:"hi"};

$('body').append
('<div style=\'display:none\' id=\'dialog\' title=\'Message\'><p>' + $scope.successMessage + '</p></div>');

$(function(){
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({autoOpen:true});
                  


             setTimeout(function()
              {
                  //alert(1);
                  $("#dialog").dialog("close") ; 
              }, 3000
              );
         
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```